# Using a radio board with Contiki-OS on lpc1347 mcu

Tags: embedded, radio, lpc, contiki-os

I am trying to build a port for Contiki on my lpc1347 board. So far I have been able to run a basic LED blinking/Hello_World Contiki process/program on my board. My next goal is to use a cc2530 radio that I have, the problem is I do not know much about this. I see that that there is already a port for cc2530, but I want to use cc2530 as a radio, so is it necessary to port contiki in that too?
I am sorry for my naivete.

Thank you.

Comment: What is Contiki?

Comment: It is an OS: http://www.contiki-os.org/.

Comment: @Dwayne can you suggest me where i can read about how radio boards work and how to program them,please!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Smart RF studio that's made available by TI. You have to type whatever the settings you want into it in a very generic sense. Then it creates several header files for you. These header files contain the register programing part as well as some APIs to call from your MCU.

If you youtube, there is a video done  by a guy who demonstrates this for TI RTOS. However, you can use the very same method for controlling the RF transceiver via an MCU too.